# Pattern Matching for Generics

Tags: c#

Trying to understand pattern matching for Generics in C#.  Let's say I have the following:

```
public interface IPerson {}

public class Person : IPerson {}
```

And now try pattern match, **result2** returns false:

```
List<IPerson> peeps1 = new List<IPerson>();
var result1 = peeps1 is List<IPerson>;  // true
List<Person> peeps2 = new List<Person>();
var result2 = peeps2 is List<IPerson>;  // false
```

What is needed to make result2 a true statement?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not pattern matching. As of your question - google "C# generics invariant"